# How to check password against previously used passwords in django

Tags: django, django-forms, django-authentication, django-users

I have the following model for storing previously used hashed passwords:

```
class PasswordHistory(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)
```

In the change password form I want check if the new password the user is changing to has not been used the past 5 times.

Here is my form validation:

```
class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password1 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(), required=False)
    password2 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(), required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Employee

        
    user_id = None
    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user_id = kwargs.pop('user_id', None)
        super(ProfileForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        
    def clean_password2(self):
        password1 = self.cleaned_data['password1']
        password2 = self.cleaned_data['password2']
        if password1 != password2:
            raise forms.ValidationError('Passwords do not match.')
        

        user = User.objects.get(pk=self.user_id)
        hashed_password = make_password(password1)
        password_histories = PasswordHistory.objects.filter(
        user=user,
        password_hashed_password
    )
    if password_histories.exists():
        raise forms.ValidationError('That password has already been used')        
    return password2
```

The problem is that the passwords are different every time, even when I attempt the same plain text password over and over again.  Therefore:

```
if password_histories.exists():
```

Never returns true.

**How can I compare past passwords if they are always different due to salt?**
Thanks

Comment: `user.set_password` does not *return* a password, it simply sets the password.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `.set_password` function indeed does not return anything, it simply *sets* the password. Like you say however, the hashing is based on a (random) salt, and thus the hash will be different each time. Therefore you should use the [**`.check_password(…)`** function [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/passwords/#django.contrib.auth.hashers.check_password), to verify if it somehow matches a hashed variant:

```
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import check_password

class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password1 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(), required=False)
    password2 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(), required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Employee
    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user_id = kwargs.pop('user_id', None)
        super(ProfileForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        
    def clean_password2(self):
        password1 = self.cleaned_data['password1']
        password2 = self.cleaned_data['password2']
        if password1 != password2:
            raise forms.ValidationError('Passwords do not match.')
        user = User.objects.get(pk=self.user_id)
        password_histories = PasswordHistory.objects.filter(
            user=user
        )
        for pw in password_histories:
            if check_password(password2, pw.password):
                raise forms.ValidationError('That password has already been used')
        return password2
```

So if we found a hashed password that matches the given *raw* password, we can return the `password`. If by the end of the `for` loop, we did not find any such password, we can return `password2`, otherwise we raise  an errro.

Comment: The make_password prints out a completely different hash for the same plain text password.

Comment: @Atma: well that is rather strange, since the `User.set_password` calls this behind the curtains: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py#L98  So unless you altered the hasher, etc. something fishy is going on. Note that you shoudl be careful not to *double hash* the password (as in hashing a hashed version already). That is why calling `.set_password` during cleaning is *not* a good idea. Since then you will often call it again in the `save` method or in the view, and thus store the hash *of the hash*.

Comment: This is the case even in the django admin.  I can set the password over and over again to the same plain text password and it will be different each time because of salt.

Comment: @Atma: ah yes, you should indeed verify the hash, not hash the password.

Comment: I like it a lot

Comment: People helping people, this is powerful stuff